# Does APNS require user approval?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm looking to implement a pub/sub mechanism with my phonegap app. I'm considering Amazon SNS which is using APNS.
I wonder if pushing data to the app requires the user approval to get push notifications (i'm not looking to show any notifications to the user).

Answer (score 0):

When the end-user of the device installs the app on a device, the user has to consent to receive push notifications from the app. This is not an SNS feature however, and is enforced by the OS (in this case iOS) as a means to allow the end-user to disable notifications for a given app if need be.

Once the end-user gives this permission upon app install, no further consent is required to push notifications to that app.

Regards,

-Sid

Comment: I don't want to display any push notification to the user. I'd like to send a message to my app. Will the user still need to approve it?